# How to get the geo location of a device in Android using Appium

Tags: appium

I need to get the device latitude, longitude and altitude of an Android device using Appium. Are there any in built method to get the geo location information like setLocation() method or do we have to use ADB commands to find the device Geo location.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, appium exposes end point for this purpose:

`GET /session/:session_id/location`

So if you are coding in `Java`, you can do:

```
Location location = driver.location();
//location.getAltitude();
//location.getLatitude();
//location.getLongitude();
```

Comment: I am getting the following error

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Method has not yet been implemented (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

I am using Java client 5.0.4

Comment: I have updated my java client to the latest 6.0.0-BETA2 but still I am getting the same error.
 io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
 at io.appium.java_client.AppiumExecutionMethod.execute(AppiumExecutionMethod.java:44)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.html5.RemoteLocationContext.location(RemoteLocationContext.java:39)
 at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.location(AppiumDriver.java:256)
 at com.vervewireless.qa.AppiumHelper.getLongitude(AppiumHelper.java:82)

Comment: I have confirmed mock location is enabled in my device

Comment: You may get such error if you are using real device: location-related methods in appium work only on emulators as there is no way to get exact value on real device. See https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/85279/a-way-to-get-location-coordinates-from-command-line

Comment: Yes, I am testing against real devices not against the emulators. Or there any other work around to get the location information in real devices apart from the adb command.

Comment: If you are using real device -> the proper way is adb, if you using paid mobile cloud -> some of them expose custom method to set/get location coordinates